# mongodb mapreduce doesn't return right in a sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, collections, mapreduce, sharding

very interesting, mapreduce works fine in a single instance, but not on a sharded collection. as below, you may see that i got a collection and write a simple map-reduce 
function,

```js
mongos> db.tweets.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5359771dbfe1a02a8cf1c906"),
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            131.71778292855996,
            0.21856835860911106
        ]
    },
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "isflu" : 1,
        "cell_id" : 60079,
        "user_id" : 35,
        "time" : ISODate("2014-04-24T15:42:05.048Z")
    }
}
mongos> db.tweets.find({"properties.user_id":35}).count()
44247
mongos> map_flow
function () { var key=this.properties.user_id; var value={ "cell_id":1}; emit(key,value); }
mongos> reduce2
function (key,values){ var ros={flows:[]}; values.forEach(function(v){ros.flows.push(v.cell_id);});return ros;}
mongos> db.tweets.mapReduce(map_flow,reduce2, { out:"flows2", sort:{"properties.user_id":1,"properties.time":1} })
```

but the results are not what i want

```js
mongos> db.flows2.find({"_id":35})
{ "_id" : 35, "value" : { "flows" : [  null,  null,  null ] } }
```

I got lots of null and interesting all have three ones.
mongodb mapreduce seems not right on sharded collection?

Comment: actually, mapreduce works fine, your functions are buggy. you are not emitting correct type (must be the same type as reduce returns). You emit a document, but you return an array.  This will break re-reducing every time since an array of arrays won't have v.cell_id - hence null.

Comment: the map-reduce function i submitted in the question is a sample to see whether mongodb could get a correct return. however, I actually try to group by the user_id and sort the collection by time, and than write down the trajectories of each user. so you see an array to hold the results. any suggestions to make things right? and are you imply mapreduce is not suitable for this task?

Comment: I pointed out the errors in the functions you posted. Those explain the "incorrect" results you are getting.  It would be better to post your actual code if you want help with it.  In my answer I tried to explain the general principle involved that your MR jobs need to adhere to.

Answer (score 1):

The number one rule of MapReduce is:

- thou shall emit the value of the same type as reduce function returneth

You broke this rule, so your MapReduce only works for small collection where reduce is only called once for each key (that's the second rule of MapReduce - reduce function may be called zero, once or many times).

Your map function emits exactly this value `{cell_id:1}` for each document.

How does your reduce function use this value?  Well, you return a value which is a document with an array, into which you push the `cell_id` value.  This is strange already, because that value was 1, so I'm not sure why you wouldn't just emit 1 (if you wanted to count).

But look what happens when multiple shards push a bunch of 1's into this flows array (whether it's what you intended, that's what your code is doing) and now reduce is called on several already reduced values:

```
reduce(key, [ {flows:[1,1,1,1]},{flows:[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}, etc ] )
```

Your reduce function now tries to take each member of the values array (which is a document with a single field `flows`) and you push `v.cell_id` to your flows array.  There is no cell_id field here, so of course you end up with `null`.  And three nulls could be because you have three shards?

I would recommend that you articulate to yourself what exactly you are trying to aggregate in this code, and then rewrite your map and your reduce to comply with the rules that mapReduce in MongoDB expects your code to follow.